# Maven for org.apache.commons.validator.routines. EmailValidator

Tags: maven

Does this dependency use to validate email? I searched and got this result, but my class can not import EmailValidator

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what is the fully qualified class name ?

Comment: It is EmailValidator. I can download the jar and include it in the lib manually. But I just want to keep it in pom.xml for flexible purpose. Hibernate offers a the validate jar that also validate email. But after several test, I think apache commons is much better for this purpose

Comment: class exists, try importing `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator`

Comment: are you using the dependency above?

Comment: This artifact contains the class you are looking for

Comment: Its said the import cant not be solved.

Comment: open that jar file in archive utility and find that class, if you find that class then there is something wrong in your project's configuration

Comment: Nvm, I just need to update maven. Thnank for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use version 1.4.1 :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: then what about in gradle

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In gradle it is: `compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'` for version 1.6